# Add a local GeoJSON file as a layer with GeoJsonLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson, layers

I turned a state boundary feature class into a `geojson` file called region2_boundary.json:

```
 {
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "crs" : {
    "type" : "name",
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "ESRI:102008"
    }
  },
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "id" : 1,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
          [
            [
              1708004.4871000014,
              329793.41640000045
            ],
           ....
  }
```

I have placed it into my `Scripts` folder in my ASP.Net app at the same level as my `app.js`. I am trying to bring it in as a layer in my `app.js` code, but there seems to be a problem. I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GeoJsonLayer is not defined

I am thinking that I am just using a bad filepath/url in my `boundaries` variable. Any suggestions on how to get this simple json file added as a layer or how to resolve this error?

```
require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/basemaps",
  "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/tasks/ImageServiceIdentifyTask",
  "esri/tasks/ImageServiceIdentifyParameters",
  "esri/layers/WebTiledLayer",
  "esri/dijit/Search",
  "esri/config",
  "esri/request",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters",
  "esri/tasks/query",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "dojo/json",
  "dojo/promise/all",
  "dojo/domReady!"], function(
    Map,
    esriBasemaps,
    BasemapToggle,
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
    ImageServiceIdentifyTask,
    ImageServiceIdentifyParameters,
    WebTiledLayer,
    Search,
    esriConfig,
    esriRequest,
    IdentifyTask,
    IdentifyParameters,
    Query,
    QueryTask,
    JSON,
    all) {
    ...
    var boundaries = "./region2_boundary.json";
    var geoJsonLayer1 = new GeoJsonLayer({
        data: boundaries
    });
    ...
    map = new esri.Map("map", {
        //basemap: "streets",
        basemap: "topo",
        center: [-66.664513,18.200178], //PR
        zoom: 9,
        layers: [geoJsonLayer1]
    });
```

**EDIT** I have added my dependencies above.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the start of the script where you define the modules to use?

Comment: Yep, just added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was already using `arcGIS Javascript API` version 3.29. The answer above obviously will not work and I had too many other dependencies using that version to change it at this point. What I found was this: [geojson-layer-js](https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js) . It can be downloaded from Github but requires that you bring in Terraformer as well. I added the geojsonlayer.js to an `src` folder in my `Asp.Net` app and created a 'vendor' folder for the Terraformer stuff. I should not that some styling and events handling had to be done in that `geojsonlayer.js` file and the layers should already be in `SpatialReference` of `wkid: 4326` or have no projection at all. I had to use some `esri` components like `SimpleMarkerSymbol()` and `SimpleRenderer` in my `app.js` file:

```
var riverine_symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
riverine_symbol.style = SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE;
riverine_symbol.setSize(8);
riverine_symbol.setColor(new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.5]));

var rivJson = {
    //"type": "simple",
    "label": "Riverine",
    "symbol": riverine_symbol
};
var riv_renderer = new SimpleRenderer(rivJson);
```

Then, when loading my map, I added the layer like this:

```
var geoJsonLayer4 = new GeoJsonLayer({
    url: "./data/riv_gauges_parsed.json",
    renderer: riv_renderer
});
```

Its a little tricky but doable. If you are reading this, I highly recommend using version 4.1 and up of the API as the tools for this are way easier.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using the 4.x version of the API since it seems `GeoJSONLayer` was implemented in 4.11.

Remember that you have to define the modules and classes you will use on top of your script. I see you are calling several modules and classes but `GeoJsonLayer` is not listed (hence the error you are getting). If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html), you will see that you need to integrate the following piece of code:

```
require(["esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer"], function(GeoJSONLayer) { /* code goes here */ });
```

Also, note that it is `GeoJSONLayer` and not `GeoJsonLayer` (althought you could name it anything you want inside `function()`).

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I am getting ane error: `GET https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

Comment: What version of the API are you using? It seems like you are using 3.x but `GeoJSONLayer` is only implemented in 4.x.

Comment: Yep, I'm using 3.x. Is there a way to do this (something similar) using the 3.x API?

Comment: I'd ask a new question because other people can give a more relevant answer than me. However, if it is not too big, I'd publish it as a service or upload it to ArcGIS Online and consume it as a FeatureLayer. Other option is to read the GeoJSON and create a FeatureSet and ultimately a FeatureLayer so you can do it on the fly rather than storing it on AGOL.